# How can I relate retries with the original send in SQL Server Database Mail?

Tags: sql-server, email

I'm using SQL Server Database Mail configured with 1 retry. The first send attempt produces a row in the msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems view. If the first send attempt fails a second send attempt is made, which produces another row in that view. The mailitem_id of the two rows differs. Is there a way to correlate the two rows so that I can identify the retry row from the mailitem_id of the first send attempt?

Comment: you may want to do  a hash bytes of columns starting from recipients to append_query_error  and self join those rows having same hash value

Comment: Turns out the original premise was wrong - the first and second attempts do not create separate rows, rather the second updates the row that the first created. So correlation is irrelevant.